# How to await until nock is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I'm not sure if `nock` is supporting awaiting or notifying using callback / event-emitter when the interceptor is called.

For example:

```
const scope = nock(config.research.url)
                   .post(config.research.routes.getOdds, expectBody)
                   .reply(200)

while(true){
  expect(scope.isDone()).toBeTruthy()
  await sleep(500)
}
```

#### My Question

How can I improve the above code using `nock` API?

Comment: What is the `nock` function do?

Comment: You could wrap the `nock` call in a function that returns a promise which resolves with the value you need. Then you should be able to `await` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nock` emits event on request and response: https://github.com/nock/nock/#events

```
emit('request', function(req, interceptor, body))
emit('replied', function(req, interceptor))
```

Your code can listen to the `replied` event to get notified.

Answer (score 3):

`nock` allows to pass a callback to the `reply` function this can be one of the ways to handle that. Wrap your `reply` code into a `Promise` and wait for it.

Another solution could be to subscribe to the `replied` event that scope emits and wrap it into a `Promise` to wait for a reply

```
 scope.on('replied', function(req, interceptor) { ... })
```